# Which C# library use to consume QPID queues

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, messagebroker

I tried to connect a Apache QPID broker with a RabbitMQ.Client (5.1.0) C#, but I got problem connection.

I am not sure that the RabbitMQ client is compatible with QPID. 
The version of the protocol AMQP is 0.9

I installed a QPID server on my computer and it looks to be be functional, including the UI.

When I ran the program, the Exception I got is :

Exception message :{"None of the specified endpoints were reachable"}

The InnerException is :
"No compatible authentication mechanism found - server offered [CRAM-MD5 SCRAM-SHA-1 SCRAM-SHA-256]"

Here is the code executed:

```
using RabbitMQ.Client;
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
        {
            HostName = "localhost",
            Port = 5672,
            UserName = "guest",
            Password = "guest",
        };

        factory.Protocol = Protocols.AMQP_0_9_1;
        try
        {             
        // Cannot connect to QPID here
        var connection = factory.CreateConnection();¨
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {             
        // catch exception 
        }
    }
}
```

1/ Does the RabbitMQ library compatible with Apache QPID broker  ? 
2/ If yes...from where does this authentication come from ?

Comment: You can't use RabbitMQ. The standard AMQP version is 1.0, which is very different from 0.9. Rabbitmq has refused to upgrade for several years now. Everyone else works on 1.0, and that includes Amazon, Azure etc. This means you can use the libraries they provide for Event Hub, Service Bus etc.

Comment: Check for example [AMPQ.Net Lite](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite), a general purpose AMQP client, and the [AMQP section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-overview) in the Azure Service Bus documentation.

Comment: Exception throw by client (amqpnetlite version 2.16):
"sasl-mechanisms(sasl-server-mechanisms:[CRAM-MD5,SCRAM-SHA-1,SCRAM-SHA-256])"
I thought it was about incompatibility.
I tried this 2 different connections with the same result..

This.connection = new Connection(address, SaslProfile.Anonymous, new Open() { ContainerId = "client.1.2", HostName = "127.0.0.1", MaxFrameSize = 8 * 1024 }, null);
This.connection = new Connection(address, SaslProfile.Anonymous, null, null);
Do you have any ideas ?